# join a user to telegram channel automatically?

Tags: java, android, telegram

I want to join a user to a telegram channel automatically.
I have telegram source , in this source after a user log in to the telegram for the first time , I add my user to specific telegram channel.

I just want to add user to the channel .I search it and I found just open a channel by this piece of code:

```
 Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
 i.setData(Uri.parse("https://t.me/CafeKetab"));
 final String appName = "com.telegram.mahsaaa";
 i.setPackage(appName);
 i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
 ApplicationLoader.applicationContext.startActivity(i);
```

I just want to know , is it possible to do this?
how I change my code to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, surely it's possible. However, these steps are required before you do it:

1. Obtain your own API ID and API HASH [as described here](https://core.telegram.org/api/obtaining_api_id).
2. User MUST authenticate phone number within your app. This means an SMS will be sent to user phone.

After the above steps, all you have to do is to invoke these two requests in order:

1. `contacts.resolveUsername#f93ccba3` to get `id` and `access_hash` from a `@username`.
2. `channels.joinChannel#24b524c5` to join the channel.

Telegram has its own [MTProto](https://core.telegram.org/mtproto). There are several libraries you can use to call the above functions. Unfortunately most of them are buggy. You may take a look at [this code](https://github.com/DrKLO/Telegram/blob/master/TMessagesProj/src/main/java/org/telegram/tgnet/ConnectionsManager.java) to get an idea.

Comment: how to do it programically , now i do first steps ,i mean that I have API ID and API HASH  and phone number.  I can not understand you. how to it programically? is this a piece of code?

Comment: If you send me the source code you're using as base, I will be able to show you usage.

Comment: I use this source code https://github.com/DrKLO/Telegram, in log in activity I just want to do this action. is there any way to have contact with you to explain me

Comment: I've updated the answer, please check the code I linked. I can't code for you, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't do this except you write a bad Telegram client.

No official reference about this, but as you know, Telegram is very cares about privacy.

Answer (score 0):

So you want help to program a PUP / spam app? Probably this should be flagged, but I don't know about such cases. I just reminds me of the cryptocurrency spammers in Telegram...